# USB device not working properly on Mac Pro 5,1

Tags: usb, monterey, mac-pro, macos

Mac OS Monterey running on Mac Pro 5,1 patched with Open Core Legacy Patcher

I have observe the following odd behaviour.

- Attach a microsoft mouse to one of the back USB ports.  Works.
- Detach and plug in on  front port.  Mouse LED flashes once, and mouse does not connect.
- Detach and plug in on back port again.  LED flashes.  No connect.
- Reboot mac, with mouse attached with either port.  Works.
- Attach a hub to the mac, using one of the ports that the mouse doesn't work on.  Attach mouse to hup.  Works.

I have seen this behaviour with USB keyboards too.

---

I have another mac running Big Sur. Unplugging and repluging in USB devices works as expected there.

Comment: I read this somewhere recently, but I can't remember where :\ It's an issue specific to OCLP Mac Pros; something in the USB hardware/firmware is causing this. There are two types of negotiated connection [again can't remember the names] Replugging calls the wrong type, connecting a hub makes the hub call the correct type which then reconnects other peripherals just fine. You might have to look at OCLP's site to figure out what the fault is & whether they think they may be able to correct it.

Comment: …or someone might be able to figure out from my vague waffling what exactly I mean,  & know where to get the correct full info ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Your comment should be on the half-assed answer I posted below.  (rueful grin)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer here:  [Legacy UHCI/OHCI support in Ventura #1021](https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/issues/1021)

Nutshell:  Mac Pro implements USB 1.1 and 2.0 on separate controllers, with the controller chosen when a device is added.  Connecting an older low power older device such as a mouse or keyboard forces that controller to switch to the 1.1 controller.

Added:  I think that the hardware defaults to 2.0 but that if present on power up, it will attach to a 1.1 device.  This explains the ability to deal with a 1.1 mouse on power up.  In addition, when the device is disconnected, the port goes back to 2.0.  In OCLP versions of pushing a later OS on earlier hardware, the machine doesn't know how to switch back from 2.0 to 1.1.

By attaching a USB 2.0 hub the controller remains in 2.0 mode, and the older device can still be used.

This explanation contains errors, and is incomplete.  I invite corrections.